# Concubines/ Slaves

Tags: women, sex, slavery

I am confused on how slavery works in Islam, I have no problem with it just would like to know the rulings.

If your sister by some means becomes your slave can you have intercourse with her?

Answer (score 1):

No. The mahrams due to lineage, suckling or marriage are also forbidden in concubinage.

Further, if your sister is a slave and you somehow come to own her then she becomes free automatically, according to the majority of the madhabs.

> من ملك ذا رحم محرم فهو حر
>
> If anyone gets possession of a relative who is within the prohibited degrees, that person becomes free.
>
> <sup>— [Abu Dawud](https://sunnah.com/abudawud:3949)</sup>